# Does Xcode Always Compile from Scratch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I sometimes see that change I made shows up on third or 4th build run. It's as if xcode "cache" old compilation.

How to delete all compiled file and start from scratch

One thing that's particularly frustating is this:

I got a compile warning

for this code:
 [self.currentBusiness addCategoriesObject:self.currentCategory];

I know what the problem. The automatically generated core data code do not have
- (void)addDistrictsObject:(District *)value;
- (void)addCategoriesObject:(Category *)value;

on Business.h. The function is defined in Business.m though.

So I added those 2 lines. Guess what, still the same warning. I had this exact same problem several time with no issue. I know the solution. I put the line right there in business.h. Nothing changes.

Yet now I get the same compiler warning even though the method is CLEARLY defined in business.h.

As if xcode do not care about the last change I put.

I am so frustated. I added #import "Business.h" again in my utilities.h. Shouldn't change anything given that  "Business.h" is already included through other channel. Guess what, it works.

But then I thought, ah that's the problem. I curiously remove that //#import "Business.h" again so it's back like usual. If that's really the issue then the error should show up again right? Wrong.

The error is gone.

So changes I made do not show results right away. Either the compiler or the precompiler must use some sort of cache.

This is important. There are bugs that are introduced 2-3 builds before that I don't know how to debug. If code changes right after the first build after I make that change I know that something is wrong.

Also that autorestore doesn't seem to work. I create a snapshot, restore the snapshot into another directory and get lots of compile error.

Comment: Follow these steps to solve the problem,  Go to Build -> Clean All Targets.   and you will be done, then again compile and run to see your changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO, It only compile the file in which any kind of any editing took place.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode does incremental builds. You can do a clean build by going to the `Product` menu item and select `Clean` (or press `Shift+Cmd+K`). That will delete all intermediate files and start from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Click xcode -> Empty Caches.

Here is a screenshot.

[image: xcode]

Comment: There is no empty Caches option

Comment: Now I get it. If one of the dependence change, xcode doesn't count that as change.